# Why apps only build on Android 11

Tags: java, android

I made an android app. The test was done with `android version 9` and `android version 11` devices.
But it works fine on `android 11` version, but gives an error on `android 9` version. I tried looking for information but couldn't find it. Thanks for your help.

**Android 9 Error Code:**

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/dreamlteks/dreamlteks:9/PPR1.180610.011/G950NKSU4DTD1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '11'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 14715, tid: 14715, name: mobile_20220531  >>> package_name <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000000000000d  x2  756f43656c69466e  x3  6f6300203a20746e
    x4  0000000000000028  x5  0000800000000000  x6  6e61ff1f391f736d  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
    x8  0000000000000000  x9  ffffffffffffffff  x10 0000007d5b9d99d0  x11 ffffffffffffffff
    x12 ffffffffffffffff  x13 0000000000000001  x14 0000007dfb17d000  x15 ffffffffffffffff
    x16 0000007d5b9a3910  x17 0000007d5b92b824  x18 0000000000000000  x19 0000007d74c14c00
    x20 0000000000000000  x21 0000007d74c14c00  x22 0000007fc24b7340  x23 0000007d5e2f242d
    x24 000000000000000c  x25 0000007dfb6c35f8  x26 0000007d74c14ca0  x27 0000000000000003
    x28 0000007fc24b7070  x29 0000007fc24b6b90
    sp  0000007fc24b6b80  lr  0000007d5b92a6a4  pc  0000007d5b92b83c
```

**Error Source:**

```
ptr_entry_info = (st_entrymodel_info *)malloc(entry_cnt * sizeof(st_entrymodel_info))
```

**More information**

```
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000000000da114  /data/app/com.example.elfscoreprint_mobile_20220531-gO-SIf7DRkP95RhmXzloqg==/base.apk (offset 0x4929000) (_JNIEnv::NewByteArray(int)+24)
    #01 pc 00000000000d8f78  /data/app/com.example.elfscoreprint_mobile_20220531-gO-SIf7DRkP95RhmXzloqg==/base.apk (offset 0x4929000) (MainControll::LogStrInt(char*, int, int, int, int, int)+160)
    #02 pc 00000000000d8d30  /data/app/com.example.elfscoreprint_mobile_20220531-gO-SIf7DRkP95RhmXzloqg==/base.apk (offset 0x4929000) (Java_com_example_elfscoreprint_1mobile_120220531_MainActivity_GetFileData+640)
    #03 pc 000000000056afe0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144)
    #04 pc 0000000000561f88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
    #05 pc 00000000000d0140  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
    #06 pc 00000000002865e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
    #07 pc 00000000002805a4  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+948)
    #08 pc 0000000000531240  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+584)
    #09 pc 0000000000554614  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
    #10 pc 00000000000604f0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.example.elfscoreprint_mobile_20220531-gO-SIf7DRkP95RhmXzloqg==/base.apk_32135_32135 (deleted) (com.example.elfscoreprint_mobile_20220531.MainActivity.a+988)
    #11 pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2089273699+496)
    #12 pc 000000000025fc20  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
    #13 pc 0000000000280588  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
    #14 pc 0000000000532580  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+296)
    #15 pc 0000000000554714  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
    #16 pc 00000000000600fc  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.example.elfscoreprint_mobile_20220531-gO-SIf7DRkP95RhmXzloqg==/base.apk_32135_32135 (deleted) (com.example.elfscoreprint_mobile_20220531.MainActivity.b)
    #17 pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2089273699+496)
    #18 pc 000000000025fc20  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
    #19 pc 0000000000280588  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
    #20 pc 0000000000531240  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+584)
    #21 pc 0000000000554614  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
    #22 pc 000000000005eefc  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.example.elfscoreprint_mobile_20220531-gO-SIf7DRkP95RhmXzloqg==/base.apk_32135_32135 (deleted) (com.example.elfscoreprint_mobile_20220531.a.onMethodCall+4)
    #23 pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2089273699+496)
    #24 pc 000000000025fc20  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
    #25 pc 0000000000280588  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
    #26 pc 00000000005321b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1392)
    #27 pc 0000000000554814  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14740)
    #28 pc 00000000000837c2  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.example.elfscoreprint_mobile_20220531-gO-SIf7DRkP95RhmXzloqg==/base.apk_32135_32135 (deleted) (io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage+34)
    #29 pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2089273699+496)
    #30 pc 000000000025fc20  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
    #31 pc 0000000000280588  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
    #32 pc 00000000005321b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1392)
    #33 pc 0000000000554814  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14740)
    #34 pc 0000000000078760  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.example.elfscoreprint_mobile_20220531-gO-SIf7DRkP95RhmXzloqg==/base.apk_32135_32135 (deleted) (io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler+36)
    #35 pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2089273699+496)
    #36 pc 0000000000521980  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032)
    #37 pc 000000000056b0fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
    #38 pc 00000000000144d8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache_32135_32135 (deleted) (io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.a+248)
    #39 pc 0000000000561f88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
    #40 pc 00000000000d0140  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
    #41 pc 00000000002865e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
    #42 pc 00000000002816b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+752)
    #43 pc 0000000000533db4  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirectRange+244)
    #44 pc 0000000000554a14  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+15252)
    #45 pc 00000000000787c0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.example.elfscoreprint_mobile_20220531-gO-SIf7DRkP95RhmXzloqg==/base.apk_32135_32135 (deleted) (io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.b)
    #46 pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2089273699+496)
    #47 pc 000000000025fc20  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
    #48 pc 0000000000281694  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+724)
    #49 pc 0000000000532a78  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualRange+576)
    #50 pc 0000000000554914  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14996)
    #51 pc 000000000007787c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.example.elfscoreprint_mobile_20220531-gO-SIf7DRkP95RhmXzloqg==/base.apk_32135_32135 (deleted) (io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.c.run+24)
    #52 pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2089273699+496)
    #53 pc 0000000000521980  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032)
    #54 pc 000000000056b0fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
    #55 pc 00000000000146a0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache_32135_32135 (deleted) (android.os.Handler.handleCallback+64)
    #56 pc 000000000056224c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
    #57 pc 00000000000d0160  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
    #58 pc 00000000002865e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
    #59 pc 00000000002805a4  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+948)
    #60 pc 0000000000532744  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
    #61 pc 0000000000554794  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
    #62 pc 0000000000c4e7ac  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+8)
    #63 pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2089273699+496)
    #64 pc 000000000025fc20  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
    #65 pc 0000000000280588  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
    #66 pc 0000000000531240  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+584)
    #67 pc 0000000000554614  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
    #68 pc 0000000000c5741a  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.Looper.loop+406)
    #69 pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2089273699+496)
    #70 pc 000000000025fc20  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
    #71 pc 0000000000280588  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
    #72 pc 0000000000532744  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
    #73 pc 0000000000554794  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
    #74 pc 00000000004c1330  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread.main+220)
    #75 pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2089273699+496)
    #76 pc 0000000000521980  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032)
    #77 pc 000000000056b0fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
    #78 pc 000000000056224c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
    #79 pc 00000000000d0160  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
    #80 pc 00000000004682e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
    #81 pc 0000000000469d38  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1440)
    #82 pc 00000000003f87b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+48)
    #83 pc 000000000011f7e4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x115000) (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+180)
    #84 pc 0000000000561f88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
    #85 pc 00000000000d0140  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
    #86 pc 00000000002865e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
    #87 pc 00000000002805a4  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+948)
    #88 pc 0000000000531240  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+584)
    #89 pc 0000000000554614  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
    #90 pc 00000000013bd79a  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
    #91 pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2089273699+496)
    #92 pc 0000000000521980  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032)
    #93 pc 000000000056b0fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
    #94 pc 0000000000e16700  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x41f000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2208)
    #95 pc 000000000056224c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
    #96 pc 00000000000d0160  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
    #97 pc 00000000004682e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
    #98 pc 0000000000467f38  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+416)
    #99 pc 000000000036ab24  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+644)
    #100 pc 00000000000b9d10  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+120)
    #101 pc 00000000000bc8d4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+780)
    #102 pc 0000000000004990  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1200)
    #103 pc 00000000000b0550  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_init+88)
```

Is there a problem because the version of the platform is `11.0.10` like in the image??
[image]

Comment: Post the rest of the stack trace and maybe we can help.  All we can tell from this is that in native code (because this is a C crash) something dereferenced a null pointer.  You left out all the info about  where.

Comment: Edited answer to add information.

Comment: Look at your MainControll::logStrInt function, the bug is in there.  Although if this is a one off I wouldn't spend too much time chasing it

Comment: I solved the problem. The bytes of the C compiler's 'long' data type and Android's 'long' data type were different, so they were not recognized as the same data. Thanks for your answer.